# Rails Devise - Forgot password asking for login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm managing the user on my system so it can be :recoverable. Everything goes fine, except when I click the link to reset the password, it asks the user to login. It doesn't makes sense, since it's going to reset by the token sent to the email. Anyone faced this problem ou knows what may be the reason? Thanks!

EDIT:

ok, got my mistake: there's an before_action authenticate_user! on my application controller. How I add an exception only for that reset password?

Comment: This is unusual behaviour from `Devise`. According to your claim, when at a login screen, you click 'Forgot your password?' and are presented with login again? You must of done something to redirect them to login.

Comment: @fbelanger No, no. It sends the email correctly. When I go to the link to reset the password is when it asks me to login!

Comment: Edit your answer to show us your `routes.rb` and anything else you suspect.

Comment: @fbelanger please check my edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the issue with your code, but I am answering your other question which is:

> How I add an exception only for that reset password?

Which I am changing to:

> Should you `authenticate_user!` within `ApplicationController`?

Obviously, since I am swithcing up the question, the answer is no.

Here is why:

1. No application requires authentication at all times. If you need to login, that means the application does not require authentication at all times. If you can "Forget your password", then you do no require authentication at all times. I've made this same mistake too...
2. The `authenticate_user!` is not designed for `ApplicationController`, because `ApplicationController` is every controller. That said, it is designed for restricting access to controllers, yes, but not `ApplicationController` specifically. The reason you have to add this in the first place is for example, only letting logged in users, edit their own articles. You wouldn't anyone to edit articles, but you do want anyone to see articles. I don't know anything about your app, but typically authentication is a case per case thing, with very particular exceptions.

So even if you have to paste: `authenticate_user!` many times, that's okay. Theres also another method (which is why I was asking for your `routes.rb`).

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb

*P.S. The answer to your first question:*

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: 'params[:controller] == "devise_passwords"'
```

or

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: 'params[:controller] == "passwords"'
```

I forget the string representation for this controller.

*But again, this is bad and does not scale well as your application grows*

Comment: Wow, I'm really thankful for all your explanation, man. For testing, I'll use the skip, but I'll really take some time to read about it and fix it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Look at your `before action` methods in whichever controller handles this page (probably the sessions controller or users controller).  My guess is you are probably calling something like `authenticate_user!` before the action for that link.

Comment: That's what I thought so. But since it's from devise, I didn't even messed with that action. I have an UsersController, with load_and_authorize_resource, but commented it, and still asks for login on my reset password link. I'll keep looking for it, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: add this line to the controller where you want to ignore the before action
      `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:name_of_action]`

Comment: in this case it's a devise action. Where can I do it?

Comment: If you don't have a controller with that action in it (it's created by Devise auto-magically) you can gain visibility/access by creating that controller.
`rails g devise NameOfController`

Comment: I don't have... in that case, I belive it would be PasswordsController, right? So, just creating a passwords controller with that skip should work?